# How to realize bulk entry data for custom objects?

Tags: visualforce, bulkification

I want to do bulk entry for data in custom objects and wonder what would be the easiest way to do so.

I have  three objects, `Timesheet` (the main object), `Type` and `Details`.
Every `Timesheet` has multiple entries of `Type`. Every `Type` can have multiple entries of `Details`.

Here is a database setup of this (simplified) example:
[image]

I am now wondering how to develop a form that allows bulk entry. `Timesheet` should be the main view, from where to enter the details. The `+` means that one can add another set of data, e.g. another detail with specific `Room`, `Time` and `Day`.

Here is a UI mockup:

[image]

*How would you realize that? What would be the easiest Visualforce setup? Can I find any fully explained example or tutorial online?*

Answer (score 1):

I posted a solution for the similar question. [Check this answer out](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5233/how-to-improve-the-functionality-of-my-oppcontactrole-vf-page/5236#5236).Maybe it can help you. My idea was that the user can simply add or remove new items per button click.

Answer (score 1):

develop main page for TimeSheet and it have custom lookup for Type and it have to show link of  Details object in custom lookup page. it is simple way.

Comment: This answer is pretty incomplete.  Could you please flesh it out with a longer explanation of what you're suggesting and how it would meet the OP's needs, or more instructions on how to actually accomplish it?